# How to get same aligment in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add the html code in `javascript` for alignment and styling. I am searching it on Google from 3 to 4 days but not getting any suitable answer. What I am looking for?
my Javascript code is :

```
function ReadCookie()
{
  var ca = document.cookie.split('%');
  alert(ca);
}

function getCookie(cname)
{
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
   {
    var c = ca[i].trim();
    if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
   }
return "";
}

function checkCookie()
{
var user=getCookie("username");
var span =  document.getElementById("file_handle");
//span.innerHTML = ''; // clear existing
if (user!="")
  {
 //document.getElementById('file_handle').innerHTML;
// span.appendChild(user);
 span.textContent = user; // it is for the test case
  }

}
```

[image: My output come in this format:]

[image: But, I want my output comes in this format]

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Your mock code is totally differnt from your question, post your `html` code.

Comment: here is my HTML code: http://pastebin.com/z5guxBuS

Comment: We don't whole page of code, it's fully confused. clearly mentioned what you tried so far?  and where you could stuck up?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean alignment of HTML elements via Jscript?

[How to add css using HTML DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)

Comment: Really can't help you when you don't explain clearly what are you trying to achieve